# spark dataframe map aggregation with alias?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aggregate-functions

I like to use spark dataframe map aggregation syntax like this:

```
jaccardDf
        .groupBy($"userId")
        .agg(
          "jaccardDistance"->"avg"
          , "jaccardDistance"->"stddev_samp"
          , "jaccardDistance"->"skewness"
          , "jaccardDistance"->"kurtosis"
)
```

Is there a way to alias the resulting columns while still using the Map syntax?  When I need to alias I do this instead

```
jaccardDf
        .groupBy($"userId")
        .agg(
          avg("jaccardDistance").alias("jaccardAvg")
          ,stddev_samp("jaccardDistance").alias("jaccardStddev")
          ,skewness("jaccardDistance").alias("jaccardSkewness")
          ,kurtosis("jaccardDistance").alias("jaccardKurtosis")
)
```

Comment: Are you sure the map sytanx result in 4 different columns? Shouldn't each new instance of `"jaccardDistance"` replace previous instance and result in single aggregation

Comment: Yes, I'm sure.  I get the usual column names when calculating and not aliasing like "avg(jaccardDistance)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.toDF()` to alias your column names with a list you define:

```
val colNames = Array("userId", "jaccardAvg", "jaccardStddev", "jaccardSkewness", "jaccardKurtosis") 

jaccardDf
    .groupBy($"userId")
    .agg(
      "jaccardDistance"->"avg",
      "jaccardDistance"->"stddev_samp",
      "jaccardDistance"->"skewness",
      "jaccardDistance"->"kurtosis")
    .toDF(colNames: _*)
```

Comment: Didn't know I could call .toDF() on a dataframe.  This is preferable to me than having to alias each column.